# Ampache cant play songs - Ajax issue

Tags: php, ajax, iis, windows-server-2012

I have installed new Windows server 2012 R2 on my server, and installed php and mysql, and IIS.

But after I extracted the Ampache files to the wwwroot folder, and installed the site through the Ampache install, it seems like the ajax can't seem to work on the Ampache.

when I tried to create a new catalog, and query songs, it didn't do nothing until I refreshed the browser, and when I hit play, it doesn't do nothing.

the Chrome console shows that there is an 500 error returned from the "ajax.server.php" file.

I think the problem is with my server, cause on my other server it works great.

any idea what could happen?

Comment: have you set up iis to actually run php?

Comment: i pity the fool who dont read this link http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-on-iis/install-and-configure-php

Comment: yes I know this link, did it all and still nothing